# How can I know wether a token can be transfered before aping in?

Tags: bsc, transfer, scam

Other than some speficif tools (tokensniffer, honeypot, poocoin...) and project-related websites, how can I spot in a smart contract whether a token has any restriction (lock-up period, volume etc...)  with regards to its transferability.

I am asking this because I recently came across a token (https://bscscan.com/address/0x096901cE2C5501eAE23AF2D3F6e465dE98BFc645#code)  for which analysis returned clean results, but no one was able to sell more than a ridiculous quantity of the token (c.2$) I suppose to fool the 1$ test. Turned out to be a honeypot ofc.

Do not hesitate to be very specific with the code in smart contracts.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but there are no fool-proof ways to detect such things. There are a million ways to make a token not transferable. And even if the token was transferable at the time of the check, maybe it's no longer transferable the next day.

The only way to be (somewhat) certain is to go through its source code and analyze it. Although it's somewhat easy to also miss something there.

Comment: Many thanks! I presume there is no obvious line in the code that would indicate any restriction? Something labeled "transferfrom" "pause" etc? Did you spot any restriction in the contract I linked?

Comment: I didn't check it - it's often not trivial to analyze a contract. The most obvious way to prevent transfers is to have some extra requirements in the transfer flow.